# Google App Engine + Jersey + IntelliJ Idea

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea, jersey

Okay so I'm having some annoying issue here. I am clearly missing something, and already been frustrating myself with this for the last 4-5 hours. 
I cannot seem to be able to create a simple GAE+Jersey up and running with IntelliJ. 
The frustrating part is that I do not get any errors, just that the REST service is not present after deployment.

I've tried out a few basic stuff, basically everything you can find on Google (and here).
After some frustration I've downloaded this project: https://github.com/BluerockInteractive/GAE-Jersey-Guice-Sample
Just cause this will list out the available servers, plus the deeper logging level. 
Now here's the output of the AppEngine startup:

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B42XvjSlpDCtTTdwQl9MSTBlQ0U

So my problem: The AppEngine is up and running. If I create a basic servlet everyting works fine. However, I cannot get Jersey to work. In every form I could try it always throws an

HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /jerseyguicesample. Reason: 
    NOT_FOUND

Powered by Jetty://

Any ideas, what I could be missing here? 
Here's an image of the IDE and the artifact settings: http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/7913/20120428124133.png

Thanks,  :D

Comment: Hey, I've been stuck for quite a long time setting GAE, Jersey on IntelliJ. Can you share a sample project, if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example has REST handlers mapped to `/rest/test`, `/rest/players/{name}/xml`, `/rest/players/{name}/json` and `/rest/hello`.

What (and where) did you map `/jerseyguicesample` to?

Comment: Indeed, the sample has `/jerseyguicesample` link in `index.html` which is not mapped to anything, so it's a problem of the sample. I've verified that `/rest/hello` and other mentioned links work fine.

Comment: Now, then. Indeed. My bad. :( Thanks :D